# Getting error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)" when running iOS simulator for the first time

Tags: ios-simulator

Getting error

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig)
>   server died)"

when running iOS simulator for the first time on a blank single view application.

Any recommendations on solving this problem?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have?  What's the output of `xcrun simctl list`?  Do you see anything interesting in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 10.0 Simulator error "Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115570/xcode-10-0-simulator-error-mach-error-308-ipc-mig-server-died)

Comment: Just Quit your simulator and run the app again it will fix this issue