# Xcode 10.0 Simulator error "Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died"

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode Simulator won't boot. After running the project the simulator does not boot and the load bar is stuck at the end. Also it shows this error after I closed the simulator showing this error

```
 The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

8 months ago the answer. This problem occurs when you install an alternative Xcode version like betas or previous versions. To solve this problem you need reinstall Xcode command line tools.

As there is no reinstall option in `xcode-select` command you need to remove the current command line tools as bellow:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Verify if `xcode-select` is the right path

```sh
xcode-select -p
```

The output is similar to:

```sh
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Reinstall the command line tools

```sh
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Now you need to **reboot** the system.

After reboot your system you need to launch the Xcode. Son after the Xcode additional components will appear.

[image: Xcode additional required components]

After concluding the installation your simulator works right.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me, Simulator is still dying and I'm getting that error upon quitting Simulator after reinstalling the tools.

Comment: @JordanH what Xcode version do you use? What your architecture?

Comment: 14.1 Apple silicon

Comment: same issue is still on macbook m1 + xcode 14.2 + ios 16.2

Comment: Hi @RuslanSabirov, I never did get the issue with Apple Silicon. Did this start after an Xcode upgrade or after an OS update?

Comment: Hello @TheOliverDenis, can't say for sure. I had updated os and xcode simultaneously. A lot of people experience the same problem.